# How can I scrape javascript computed value using JSOUP?

Tags: javascript, jsoup

I am scraping my website data and it's going good but now I am stack scraping the JavaScript var value. Can you help me please ?

My script is

```js
var minute1 = 34;
var minutes = 21 + minute1;
```

I would like to get minutes value that is 55 using JSOUP thanks.

Comment: it must be `var ` not `Var`!!

Comment: yeah edited it's var with small letter, can u help me scraping it?

Answer (score 0):

JSOUP does not implement a full browser under the hood, nor does it execute JavaScript in the HTML it parses.

To get that value you need to locate the `<script>` element in the DOM and process the text inside it yourself (e.g. use regular expressions to find the number after `minute1 =` and the number between `minutes=` and `+minute1` and then add them together yourself).

Comment: thanks for the answer, I did tried to get the value of minutes using pattern and matcher but the result is  21+minute1.      Is there another way to solve this ?